# Android Studio Gradle Already disposed Module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have installed Android Studio version 1.0.1. I have imported my projects from eclipse and it works fine.
Then I deleted a module and reimported it into my Android Studio project. The gradle build says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" but it pops up an alert window with the message

**Failed to complete Gradle execution.
Cause:
Already disposed: Module: 'MYMODULENAME'**

I can't start my app now. Any idea what I can do?

**Edit:**
I solved the problem with the following instructions:

1. Switch project view from Android to Project
2. Remove entry include 'MYMODULENAME' in settings.gradle
3. The blue box in the module symbol don't show. Then you can delete the module in the context menu
4. Import the module

Comment: This seems like a bug... Have you filed one ?

Comment: Oded Breiner gave the right answer. This happens when you rename and then forget to delete the iml file

Comment: Just reimport the project into Android Studio.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

**Note**: *this is purely an IDEA/AS issue, `gradlew clean` | Build > Clean | Build > Rebuild will just waste your time.*

Most of the solutions here are blind stabbings in the dark. Here's what I found to be the root cause:

1. Some of the `.iml` files may be missing (maybe because we deleted it), 
   check if the module erroring has `.iml`.
2. If it is missing, check if `.idea/modules.xml` has an entry for that module

While syncing I noticed that IDEA/AS tries to put a new duplicate entry into `.idea/modules.xml` while there's already one. This duplicate entry is probably disposed of twice while the sync tries to reset the modules in memory.

**Quick Solution**: In order to make it work the easiest is to delete `.idea/modules.xml` along with the `.iml` files. Additionally may worth deleting `.idea/modules/` folder if it exists. Restart Android Studio (no need to clear cache) and force a Gradle sync from Gradle view or toolbar to recreate the files.

Comment: For lazy copy pasters: `find . -name *.iml -delete && rm .idea/modules.xml`, sync Android Studio

Comment: Thanks very much on the insight. 
In my case there were two entries for the `app` module in `modules.xml`

Comment: This works but Android Studio (3.4.1) keeps doing this to me when I switch projects. It will also keep trying to sync the previous module that i had open. Is there a long term solution for this?

Comment: @BenWilkinson Didn't notice in 3.4.1 the two projects I open are the same codebase from different clones. Although I choose "new window" most of the time. I would close AS, clean up both projects and hope that after the new sync they settle in.

Comment: for mac users `find . -name "*.iml" -exec rm '{}' + &&  rm .idea/modules.xml`

Answer (score 278):

I figured out this problem by:

1. `./gradlew clean`
2. Restart Android Studio

Comment: Its worked but I didn't get why its download gradle version ,I have already configure the latest gradle 2.2

Comment: The 3rd time I came here to read that I have to restart Android Studio #eclipseflashback

Comment: Grandle and Android Studio are simply shameful: I removed a module via the GUI and it started to give me this errors.

Comment: thought first it didn't work but forgot to restart :D then it worked thx

Comment: Instead of command line, i did the same via Build->Clean Project option in studio menu, and then restart. Just in case anyone having issue using command line, this is simpler. Does the same thing. :)

Comment: Didn't work for me when using Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1

Answer (score 102):

Simplest solution. (Try this first).

1. Quit and Restart Android studio. (Quit not close)
2. Build > Clean your project if needed.

Answer (score 85):

works for me:
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Yep!!! A hard invalidation of caches is sometimes the only way to fix these things.

Comment: Infuriating that we still have to do this in 2019!

Comment: From all the other suggestions from users in this thread (`./gradlew clean`, to delete some project files, etc.), this was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes `gradlew clean` or `Invalidate Cache and Restart` does not help, because these methods do not clean Android Studio specific files by themselves.

In this case, close AS and remove `.idea` directory and `.iml` file in a root project where `settings.gradle` file exists. This will make AS rebuild from the fresh ground.

Comment: I think this is the most robust solution

Comment: This solution solved my issue when i upgrade my Android Gradle to the build:gradle:3.5.0-rc02

Answer (score 6):

For me this happened when i deleted a module and built a new one with the same package name 
Solution:

> Clean & Restart Studio

Answer (score 5):

1. In the left pane, change to "Project" view.
2. Delete MYMODULENAME.iml

Comment: Delete mymodulename.iml

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative solution, check if you added your app to settings.gradle successfully

```
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this happened when I removed a module and tried to build the project:

Simple solution was to Invalidate the cache & Restart.

Android Studio>File>Invalidate Caches>Invalidate & Restart

Comment: invalidate and restart is best saviour

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue when working with RN components in my Android project and the only way to get around this issue was to ignore the gradle project.

To do this:

- Click on the gradle tab on the right hand side of AS
- Right click the gradle module which is causing an issue
- Click "Ignore Gradle Project"
- Perform a gradle sync which should be successful now
- If you need this module perform the 4 above steps again, this time when right click on the gradle project it'll show "Unignore Gradle Project"
- Gradle sync should now work

No idea what causes this but I've had this happen to me when using React Native Maps.

Note: If you're still having issues following this. Try to refresh the gradle project which was causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

If `gradle clean` and/or `Build -> Clean Project` didn't help try to re-open the project:

- Close the project
- Click "Open an existing Android Studio project" on the "Welcome to Android Studio" screen
  [image]
- Select gradle file to open

**Warning** Be aware it's a destructive operation - you're going to loose the project bookmarks, breakpoints and shelves

Answer (score 1):

below solution works for me

1. Delete all `.iml` files
2. Rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

For Solve this issue take it this simple steps.

1. Find the `.idea` folder in your Android studio under the Folder **`Project`**.
2. In `.idea` --> Find this one. `.idea/.modules`
3. Simple **Delete** that `.modules` folder and restart Your studio.
4. when it reopens gradle sync Automatically and also recreate `.modules` folder and files.
5. Error has gone !

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem sometimes. Click on gradle console in bottom bar of android studio, at right side. It will show the exact error in logs. My problem was that I had compile SDK 22 and imported appcomact library was of sdk 23.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
after delete some gradle files (of aws)

i solved it by mark them "ignore gradle"

I believe it is not the best answer but it solve it for me

Gradle (at the right bar)--> right click on the problematic gradle --> ignore

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer didn't work for me (unfortunately I can't leave a comment), it led me in the right direction.

in `.idea/libraries` i found that there were some duplicate xml files (the duplicates were named with a 2 before the `_aar.xml` bit).

deleting those, restarting android studio and sync fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009423/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-already-disposed/52574006), it happened because I had my project in a symbolic link directory. After reopening the project in the real directory and reconfiguring gradle (`File -> Sync with Gradle files`) the problem went away. Shame on you, Android Studio!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue because `gradle` and `Android Studio` were using a different path for the `jvm`. In the `Event Log` there was an option for AS and `gradle` to use the same path. Selecting this and then doing an `invalidate cache & restart` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Invalidate cached, remove .idea folder, .gradle folder,
all of them does not work, So I remove the full project, then clone the repo again. it solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Since the accepted answer didn't work for me here's a solution that did:

- You can use [this program](https://awakening.fun/AnSD?1=ASPF) I made, and give it the project(s) folder and wait for it to say "Done." (The process might take some time),
- or you can do it by hand and deleate the ".gradle" and ".idea" folders in the project folder and the "build" folder in any of it's subdirectories.

After any of the above processes is done an "Invalidate Caches... / Invalidate Caches and Restart" is needed if Android Studio was running otherwise you can just launch it.