# How to undo deleting a module in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-build

I just deleted a module that contained the source code of my application. For this reason, I cannot debug and play my application in the emulator. In the Project view the folder does exist but in the android view doesn't exist.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried adding that module back to the build.gradle file of the project ?

Comment: How i can do that? In dependencies?

Comment: You might want to try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656023/androidstudio-module-dependencies-in-gradle

Comment: Since it says, it already exists. Try removing that module from the settings.gradle file and then reimport.

Comment: The module doesn't exist in settings.grandle file

Comment: I guess the easiest way to solve this will be to remove the project from android studio and then re import the whole thing again.

Comment: Eventually I add in the setting.grandle the module - folder that the source code lives and the module has been created again but i have problem with the other module now , it sais: Failed to complete Grandle execution , cause : already disposed: Module:'sidemenu'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27768008/1239966

Comment: thank you , finally it worked ! I just restarted the android studio and everything are ok

Comment: Great! :) Android studio sometime becomes a pain to work with for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

If you removed just the module not it's contents (through *Project Structure* dialog) and your module folder is now considered just a generic folder by Android Studio, here's how to bring it back:

Switch to `Project` mode (of the `Project` pane), open file `.idea/modules.xml` (or just hit `Ctrl[Cmd] + Shift + N` and search for `modules.xml`)

Add a `<module />` tag corresponding to your accidentally deleted module, do Gradle Sync and the module folder will once again be recognized as such.

Here's a sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/MODULE_NAME/MODULE_NAME.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/MODULE_NAME/MODULE_NAME.iml" />
      <module ...
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same situation and the easiest way to re-add the deleted module from Project Structure is by selecting the Android Mode option from the top left drop down (not sure what that called) which shows all the android specific structures.

Once you have done that you would see the file called settings.gradle.  Open that up by double clicking on it and either add a include line or use the comma and the module name with color as prefix as the string or as shown below:

**include ':pDFTron', ':signalr-sdk', ':signalr-client'**

or

**include ':pDFTron'**

**include ':signalr-sdk'**

**include ':signalr-client'**

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

Look up the folder in your actual file system (Using Explorer or Finder). If your source code exists there, you can re import it. Otherwise no one can help you.
Also consider using a VCS like github next time.

Comment: The folder does exist in the Explorer. Also, exists in the project view (not in android view) and when i go to re import it as a module from new -> module -> import existing project it says that : Project already contains module with this name. But in the Project Structure in modules this module is missing

Comment: Do the actual source files still exist in the module on the file system ?

Comment: The problem has been fixed! I just add the dir with the src code in the build grandle file !

Comment: You mean the settings.gradle file (as suggested by Vincy)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to get around Android Studio complaining the module name is in use (still). 
When you delete a module the files are still on disk and the dir is still visible.

Alternative A)  Move the deleted module dir outside the project and then import it from there (again)

Alternative B) Rename the deleted module directory and then re-import.

Step 1) Right click on the deleted module dir in the project view, and choose Refactor -> Rename
    Rename the dir with an trailing underscore
  Untick the search for references.

Step 2) Use File->New->Import module and navigate to your renamed dir.
Studio will complain "Project already contains module with this name"
Just delete the underscore from the module name to get back to the original module name
Finished Import

Stop NOW for the simple solution.  You have your module back in a directory with an underscore.

If you want to rename the directory you can refactor it again BUT Studio does not handle that correctly even if you tick all the refactor boxes
To fix this failure goto the settings.gradle file in the project dir and remove the line that maps your module name to the directory with the underscore
e.g. remove
project(':afreechart_sample').projectDir = new File('afreechart_sample_')

A rebuild should now work.

Comment: Actually just adding the module name back to the settings.gradle  include  as suggested by Vincy works just as well. At least for my simple structure