# Gradle sync failed com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-11.0.2' already disposed

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

```
I am unable to resolve this error 
"Gradle sync failed: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-11.0.2' already disposed" in android studio 3.0.1

 current version "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0"
 and "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1"
```

I tried all gms version but still not able to resolve this issue,
     can somebody please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add latest version of google play services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
```

Then Add

```
google()
```

to your  repositories in project build.gradle.
Refer this link: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Clean and rebuild your project. it will be helpfull.

Comment: try clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541838/android-studio-gradle-already-disposed-module

Comment: refer link work for me "Invalidate and Restart" thanks @Naveen you saved my day