# JetPack: "Gradle sync failed: Already disposed!"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-jetpack

I've been using Android Studio **3.1.x** on my Debian 9.0 Stretch desktop for some time now with no problems.

I recently installed Android Studio **3.2 Canary 14** (aka *JetPack*). Following the *Getting Started* instructions for JetPack, I create a new project w/Kotlin support, and choose *Activity & Fragment+ViewModel*.

When I try to sync the newly-created project (i.e. *Sync Project with Gradle Files*), **the sync fails**.

Looking in the log, I find that an assertion failed (see below):

```
2018-05-12 16:44:59,062 [ thread 43]   WARN - ea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask - Sync failed: Already disposed! 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: Already disposed!
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:179)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:651)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:656)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:480)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:469)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.dispose(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:442)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:163)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:221)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:228)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doPopulateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:120)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:97)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:39)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:86)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Already disposed!
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.disposeComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:128)
        at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleImpl.dispose(ModuleImpl.java:145)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:48)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:44)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeActionWithRecursiveGuard(ObjectTree.java:169)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeUnregistered(ObjectTree.java:181)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:140)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:129)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:125)
        at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleManagerImpl$ModuleModelImpl.dispose(ModuleManagerImpl.java:895)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.dispose(AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.java:467)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl$3.execute(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:445)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1010)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.lambda$executeProjectChangeAction$6(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:469)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:156)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:779)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:720)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:395)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2018-05-12 16:44:59,063 [ thread 43]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Already disposed! (1 s 170 ms)
```

I've tried reinstalling everything, deleting the .gradle directory, etc; no joy.

There seems to be no mention of this issue online, so I'm guessing it's something specific to my setup (vs. a known issue with JetPack), but I'm not sure where to look or what to do about it.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: By the way i never use canary version, because it is never stable.

Comment: I supposed you've tried invalidating caches?

Comment: @levi-albuquerque - Yeah, invalidate-and-restart makes no difference either.

Comment: @khemraj - But the latest stable release (for Linux 64-bit) is 3.1.2, and JetPack's *Getting Started* page says "Launch Android Studio 3.2 or higher". Is there some *other* 3.2.x version besides Canary, or should I just wait a stable release with version >= 3.2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27700914/6891563

Comment: Have you already tried this.

Comment: @khemraj - Yes, I saw that and tried all the suggested solutions. None of them resolved the problem; when I sync project with gradle files, I get the same failure.

Comment: Just to close this out, I recently updated to the latest version of JetPack, and the problem went away...

Answer (score 1):

1. Invalidate Caches... / Invalidate Caches and Restart
2. Cancel first sync
3. Open a new project
4. Migrate to a new project

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77854494/19690976) is a better solution.