# Android IDE error - AlreadyDisposedException while opening Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, configuration, ide

I have Android studio dolphin version.

While I try to open Android studio, an error dialog box appears and it shows like

> **IDE error occured**
> See details and submit report

And the report shows an error as below

```
com.intellij.serviceContainer.AlreadyDisposedException: Already disposed: Module: 'AppName.app' (disposed)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.checkState(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:184)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:533)
    at com.intellij.facet.FacetManager.getInstance(FacetManager.java:15)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.ProjectFacetManagerImpl.getIndex(ProjectFacetManagerImpl.java:76)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.ProjectFacetManagerImpl.hasFacets(ProjectFacetManagerImpl.java:100)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.ui.FacetDependentToolWindowManager$1.facetRemoved(FacetDependentToolWindowManager.java:58)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.ProjectWideFacetListenersRegistryImpl$ProjectWideFacetListenerWrapper.facetRemoved(ProjectWideFacetListenersRegistryImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.FacetEventsPublisher.onFacetRemoved(FacetEventsPublisher.kt:129)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.FacetEventsPublisher.onModuleRemoved(FacetEventsPublisher.kt:89)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.FacetEventsPublisher.access$onModuleRemoved(FacetEventsPublisher.kt:17)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.FacetEventsPublisher$1.moduleRemoved(FacetEventsPublisher.kt:29)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.java:645)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:624)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:390)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:372)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:33)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.moduleRemoved(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.ModuleManagerBridgeImpl.fireEventAndDisposeModule(ModuleManagerBridgeImpl.kt:63)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.ModuleManagerComponentBridge.processModuleChange(ModuleManagerComponentBridge.kt:181)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.ModuleManagerComponentBridge.access$processModuleChange(ModuleManagerComponentBridge.kt:45)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.ModuleManagerComponentBridge$2$changed$1.invoke(ModuleManagerComponentBridge.kt:126)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.ModuleManagerComponentBridge$2$changed$1.invoke(ModuleManagerComponentBridge.kt:74)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.UtilsKt.executeOrQueueOnDispatchThread(utils.kt:13)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.ModuleManagerComponentBridge$2.changed(ModuleManagerComponentBridge.kt:102)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.WorkspaceModelTopics$EventsDispatcher.changed(WorkspaceModelTopics.kt:118)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.java:645)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:624)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:390)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:372)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:33)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.changed(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.WorkspaceModelImpl.onChanged(WorkspaceModelImpl.kt:112)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.WorkspaceModelImpl.access$onChanged(WorkspaceModelImpl.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.WorkspaceModelImpl$updateProjectModel$2.invoke(WorkspaceModelImpl.kt:75)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.WorkspaceModelImpl$updateProjectModel$2.invoke(WorkspaceModelImpl.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.storage.impl.VersionedEntityStorageImpl.replace(VersionedEntityStorageImpl.kt:183)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.WorkspaceModelImpl.updateProjectModel(WorkspaceModelImpl.kt:75)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.jps.serialization.JpsProjectModelSynchronizer$applyLoadedStorage$1.run(JpsProjectModelSynchronizer.kt:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.lambda$runAndWait$2(WriteAction.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:935)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:961)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.compute(WriteAction.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.lambda$computeAndWait$3(WriteAction.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteThread.lambda$submit$0(WriteThread.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteThread.lambda$submit$1(WriteThread.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLaterOnWriteThread$10(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:187)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:492)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.computeAndWait(WriteAction.java:158)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.computeAndWait(WriteAction.java:128)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.runAndWait(WriteAction.java:114)
        at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.jps.serialization.JpsProjectModelSynchronizer.applyLoadedStorage(JpsProjectModelSynchronizer.kt:209)
        at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.jps.serialization.JpsProjectModelSynchronizer.loadProject(JpsProjectModelSynchronizer.kt:229)
        at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.jps.serialization.DelayedProjectSynchronizer.runActivity(DelayedProjectSynchronizer.kt:23)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runStartupActivity(StartupManagerImpl.kt:312)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivityAndMeasureDuration(StartupManagerImpl.kt:293)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivityAndMeasureDuration$default(StartupManagerImpl.kt:288)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$runPostStartupActivities$1$1.run(StartupManagerImpl.kt:245)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWithWaitForSmartModeDisabled(DumbServiceImpl.java:645)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$runPostStartupActivities$1.accept(StartupManagerImpl.kt:244)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$runPostStartupActivities$1.accept(StartupManagerImpl.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointImpl.java:299)
        at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointName.java:144)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivities(StartupManagerImpl.kt:239)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$runPostStartupActivities(StartupManagerImpl.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$projectOpened$3$1.run(StartupManagerImpl.kt:189)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.runUnderDisposeAwareIndicator(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:277)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.runUnderDisposeAwareIndicator(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:255)
        at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$projectOpened$3.run(StartupManagerImpl.kt:189)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

And also another dialog box appears as

> **Unable to save settings**
> Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

On the top, in the configuration tab, it now shows **Add Configuration** where it showed **app** with an android icon previously.

The project explorer keeps on loading forever. The same problem occurs whenever I try to create a new project as well.

There is no **modules.xml** file and some folders in the **.idea** folder are missing which the previous projects have.

**What I have tried so far**

- Invalidated caches and Restarted
- Deleted .idea and .app folder and restarted
- Created a new project to check if the same error occurs
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Android studio
- Clicked on Repair IDE and followed the steps
- Installed previous android studio versions and checked

But none the above steps seem to help resolve the issue.

Comment: Please check this hopefully it will help you out!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575658/1352919

Comment: Could you elaborate that answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post, but it's relating to a similar issue and might still be of use:

[Android Studio - Gradle sync failed: Already disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009423/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-already-disposed)

As stated,

> As it turned out, the problem was that I was trying to open a project directory that was a symlink to the actual location (on the same partition). Gradle (on command line) had no issues building the project from the symlinked location, however, opening it in Android Studio resulted in the obscure and non helpful error described above.

Also, some have reported this worked for them:

1. Delete module folder and modules.xml file under .idea folder.
2. Close Android Studio
3. Reopen and sync

So it might effectively be because your module.xml file is missing

Comment: Can you elaborate that answer by explaining what is symlink ?

Answer (score 0):

For me what helped was (ignoring the root cause of this issue)
removing the project from my local machine
and cloning it again. Then reopening it in AS.
I am on Mac btw.

(Try to restart AS (or Intelli) and clear cache first, before doing this.)

Basically:

1. Close Android Studio
2. `rm -rf Project-Directory`
3. git clone via commandline (or AS, both works)
4. reopen AS and import project

Since I don't have time to fiddle around with all the possible options
that you find on the net, to fix this issue, this was the fasted approach.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with this for hours and trying to find a solution I decided on the following which worked:

Recreate the project from scratch and fill in the project skeleton with the Java class files, drawables and other resources, manifest etc from the original project.

Not a quick solution but at least it got me moving forward again.